# Convert varchar data to time format in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, varchar

I currently have a range of transaction data, and I am trying to query the data for the sum of transactions within a certain time frame. One field, transaction_time is a varchar. An example of one of these times is "13:42", which corresponds to 1:42pm. I was experimenting around with to_timestamp, but I have been unable to figure it out. Would anyone have any idea as to how to alter this varchar to represent time data.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Casting can be done two ways:

```
select cast('12:47' as time)
```

and

```
select '12:47'::time
```

Answer (score 0):

cast it to time.

```
select cast('13:42' as time)
```